# SQL - Null value should match with not null value with another table

Tags: sql

Table 1

```
Column1    Column2   Column 3  
A           Null       12

B           Null       15

C           0          15
```

Table 2

```
Column2     Column3

0            15

0            12
```

I have table 1 and Table 2 , Here I'm passing table 2 parameters to table 1 which should return the column1 but it should match with Null values like the below scenario

If I pass  (0, 15) to table 1 then it should return 'C'  not 'B'.

If I Pass (0,12) to table 1 then it should return 'A'

Anytime it should return one value not multiple vales.

Could you please help me with this logic ?

Comment: Can you give more details on the logic that determines which rows should be returned from table1? For example, in the first scenario where (0,15) should return 'C' not 'B' - what is the logic behind this? Is it that "if there is a row in table1 where column1 is 0 then return that, otherwise if column1 is null and table2.column2 is 0 then return that?

Comment: Even we can for get about the table2. consider we are passing the parametes to the table 1 and to return the "Column1" from table 1.Here the trick is if the exact value is not found (this case its 0) then it has to match with Null value.If I pass,  0 and 15 to the column2 and column3 respectively then it should return "C" from column1. If I pass,  1 and 15 to the column2 and column3 respectively then it should return "B" from column1. (the trick is the value one should match with Null since it dont have the exact match like 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this as a union:

```
select Column1 from
(
select Table1.Column1 as Column1,Table1.Column2 as Column2
from Table1
join Table2 on
  Table1.Column2=Table2.Column2 and Table1.Column3=Table2.Column3
UNION
select Table1.Column1 as Column1,Table1.Column2 as Column2
from Table1
join Table2 on
  Table1.Column2 is NULL and Table1.Column3=Table2.Column3
) as Unioned
ORDER BY Column2 NULLS LAST
LIMIT 1;
```

The UNION discards duplicates, but you could always wrap the entire statement in another SELECT if you explicitly need to tell it to return at most one value.

Comment: Your [**query**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07e2c2/3) won't meet OP's requirement.

Comment: You can wrap everything in a SELECT, order by nulls last, then take only the top value (which has non-null Column2 if present). Modified code to do this explicitly.

Comment: Error:`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULLS LAST LIMIT 1' at line 13`. Please try the query in the fiddle I gave before updating the answer.

Comment: For MySQL you can instead do 'ORDER BY ISNULL(Column2) ASC LIMIT 1'.

Comment: Thanks for the information.I'm using MS SQl .It seems the ISNULL is not working.Anyway I will try to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table2 t
     left outer join table1 t1 on t.column2=t1.column2 and t.column3=t1.column3
     left outer join table1 t2 on t2.column2 is null and t.column3=t2.column3
where t1.column2 is not null or t2.column3 is not null
```

Comment: Your [**query**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07e2c2/1) selects `NULL` instead of `A` in second row.

Answer (score 0):

### SQL Server

```
WITH T1
    as
    (SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,
            case when COLUMN2 is null then 0 else COLUMN2 end AS TRANSFORMED_COLUMN2,
            row_number() OVER (partition by isnull(column3,2) ORDER BY isnull(COLUMN2,2) asc) AS rnk,
            COLUMN3 
    FROM    TABLE1)
    SELECT

          T1.COLUMN1,
          T2.COLUMN2,
          T2.COLUMN3
    FROM
    T1
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT COLUMN2,COLUMN3 FROM TABLE2) T2
    ON T1.TRANSFORMED_COLUMN2 = T2.COLUMN2
       AND T1.COLUMN3=T2.COLUMN3
    where T1.rnk=1
```

By using CTE, you will running through the tables just once.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now I have some more scenario added to this.Its screwed up me now.Will Explain the scenario later.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON NVL(t1.column2,0) = t2.column2 and t1.column3 = t2.column3
```